# Uncompilable source code - non-static variable Jim

Tags: java

I am new here, when I run my code i get this error.
Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-static variable Jim cannot be referenced from a static context
    at debugmetwo.BigAppleCount.generateBigAppleCount(BigAppleCount.java:7)
    at debugmetwo.BigAppleCountTest.main(BigAppleCountTest.java:10)
Java Result: 1
```

Main:

```
package AppleCount;

    public class BigAppleCountTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            BigAppleCount bac = new BigAppleCount();
            bac.generateBigAppleCount();
        }
    }
```

Class:

```
package AppleCount;

public class AppleCount {
    public int Jim = 10; 
    public int Gray = 15; 
    public int Bill = 16; 
}
```

SubClass:

```
package AppleCount;

public class BigAppleCount {
    public void generateBigAppleCount(){
        System.out.printf("How many apple Jim has: %,d\n",
                    AppleCount.Jim);
        System.out.printf("How many apple Gray has: %,d\n",
                    AppleCount.Gray);
        System.out.printf("How many apple Bill has: %,d\n",
                    AppleCount.Bill);
    }
}
```

Comment: What results did you find after researching the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do as it says

```
public class AppleCount {
    public static int Jim = 10; 
    public static int Gray = 15; 
    public static int Bill = 16; 
}
```